# Dynamically display the result of a MySQL query into an HTML page

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, yii

I use the YII Framework and I would like to put the results of a MySQL query in a table in index.php.

The MySQL query is already good:

```
SELECT categories.name,
    systemes.name,
    systemes.etat_de_base,
    maintenances.name,
    maintenances.date,
    maintenances.duree 
FROM systemes_maintenances 
LEFT JOIN systemes 
ON systemes_maintenances.id_systemes = systemes.id_systemes 
LEFT JOIN categories 
ON systemes.id_categories = categories.id_categories 
LEFT JOIN maintenances 
ON systemes_maintenances.id_maintenances = maintenances.id_maintenances;
```

And my PHP page looks like this at the moment:

```
<?php
/* @var $this SiteController */

$this->pageTitle=Yii::app()->name;
?>

<!--<h1>Welcome to <i><?php echo CHtml::encode(Yii::app()->name); ?></i></h1>

<p>Congratulations! You have successfully created your Yii application.</p>

<p>You may change the content of this page by modifying the following two files:</p>
<ul>
    <li>View file: <code><?php echo __FILE__; ?></code></li>
    <li>Layout file: <code><?php echo $this->getLayoutFile('main'); ?></code></li>
</ul>

<p>For more details on how to further develop this application, please read
the <a href="http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/">documentation</a>.
Feel free to ask in the <a href="http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/">forum</a>,
should you have any questions.</p>-->

<table>
    <caption>&Eacute;tat des systèmes</caption>
    <tr>
    <th>Cat&eacute;gorie</th>
    <th>Nom</th>
    <th>&Eacute;tat actuel</th>
    <th>Maintenance prévue</th>
    <th>Début de l'incident</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>



</table>
```

I want to display the results in the empty `<td> </ td>`.

Does anyone know how to do it without jQuery?

Comment: Start by looking into AJAX and jQuery to dynamically call and update these `<td></td>` elements

Comment: why do you want to put data in pre written tags? you may get data from Db and display elements in html recursively based on records found in db.

Comment: I don't want, but the tags are here for show where the table are suposed to write

Comment: You definitly should use CGridView (check my answer below) - http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView

Comment: Asped I try your answer, but for the moment he dosen't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To connect to the database and the connection was defined in the config yii. Must be added to the top of page two line of code.

```
$sql = 'querySQL';
$connection=Yii::app()->db;
$dataReader=$connection->createCommand($sql)->query();
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using Yii framework you can use CGridView component. This give nice set of features such as sorting, pagination and filtering.
Check following link for example usage.
http://www.yiiplayground.com/index.php?r=UiModule/dataview/gridView

Answer (score 0):

their is a tutorial How to display data in php from Mysql.

Link: http://hightechnology.in/how-to-display-data-in-php-from-mysql/

may it will help you.

Comment: It's a good track, but I use the Framework YII making process diferant

Comment: if you want to use the whole process of Yii, then you should probably start with creating a model and relations, and not selecting SQL directly

Comment: The model and the relations are already define and the CRUDE works. I did not track to direct me on how to proceed at this time.

Answer (score 0):

Try sth like this:

```
   $query = "SELECT categories.name,
        systemes.name,
        systemes.etat_de_base,
        maintenances.name,
        maintenances.date,
        maintenances.duree 
        FROM systemes_maintenances 
        LEFT JOIN systemes 
        ON systemes_maintenances.id_systemes = systemes.id_systemes 
        LEFT JOIN categories 
        ON systemes.id_categories = categories.id_categories 
        LEFT JOIN maintenances 
        ON systemes_maintenances.id_maintenances = maintenances.id_maintenances";

    $count= Yii::app()->db->createCommand($query)->queryScalar();

    $dataProvider = new CSqlDataProvider($query, array(
           'totalItemCount'=>(int) $count,
           'keyField' => 'SOME_UNIQUE_ID_FROM_THE_SQL',
           'pagination'=>array( 'pageSize'=>30, ),
    ));

    $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
      'id'=>'yourGrid',
      'dataProvider'=> $dataProvider,
    ));
```

You will have to customize the grid yourself, so that it displays only what you need, but you can find this in the Yii documentation of [CGridView](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView)

Comment: normally you should put the data selction in the Controller, but I would start that way, that you put it in your view, you test if it works and then make it nice. I didn't say it will work, I have not tested it(as I dont have you models etc..). Try to read the documenation a bit, and if sth does not work, at least try to find out what it is

Answer (score -2):

I am not so sure of the YII framework but this should definitely help you out.

Let the result of the mySql query be in a variable **$result**

now , start with while/for loop like this :

```
<?php

while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    //Do something with the $row variable data
?>
    <td>Some Data</td>
    <td>echo $row["SomeColoumn1"];</td>
    <td>echo $row["SomeColoumn2"];</td>
    <td>echo $row["SomeColoumn3"];</td>
    <td>echo $row["SomeColoumn4"];</td>
<?php    
}

?>
```

This should print all the rows of the table as required and add the **table** and **th** parts before and after accordingly.

Comment: forget this, this is way not the thing you want to do. The whole MVC model would be for nothing then and also the DB implementation.. you would not need Yii